# Why does the path between 2 corners of rectangle look strange?

Tags: shortest-path, a-star

I wrote a little program to find the shortest path between two points using the [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

I made every 10th pixel in a rectangle a node (width: 100 nodes, height: 50 nodes) and connected it with the 4 nodes lying around it (top, left, bottom, right). The program had to find the fastest way from the top left corner to the bottom right corner. This is how the result looked:

[image: Shortest Path no diagonals]

At first I wondered why if this was actually the fastest way but then I thought that I should probably add diagonal connections. This is how it looked afterwards:

[image: Shortest path with diagonal connections]
It took 100 nodes to get to the end and ca. 1193px.
This irritated me even more and now I'm wondering if my program is wrong or if that is actually the shortest way.

What do you think?

Is it not faster to take the same path like in the first picture, just going diagonally in the end?

Comment: Btw, sorry for the bad title. Feel free to change it but I could'nt think of a better one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without diagonal moves, the fastest path would take `(width-1)+(height-1)` moves to reach the end. but with diagonals, it would be less no. of moves but we can only make `min(width-1,height-1)` diagonal moves and the rest of the moves must be non-diagonal (towards right in this particular case). So both the pictures does indeed show the shortest path your code seems to be correct.

Comment: It took 100 nodes to get to the end with a length of ca. 1193px.
Then there are probably different ways of finding the fastest way and it just chose a very weird looking one.

Comment: I cannot know why it took a weird looking path until you provide the code for the A* algorithm you implemented.

Comment: I used the one with heuristics and guessing the distance to the end node using the beeline + the current distance to start. It actually doesn't matter and it's too much work to put in the code :P
Thanks alot

Comment: You should say **a** shortest path, not **the** shortest path. I think OP is confused because he doesn't realize there are many shortest paths with the same length. In both cases his algorithm picks one of them arbitrarily because OP hasn't given it any information on how to decide which is "better"